# Get content Type order in C#

Tags: document-library, content-type, folder, ordering

I am building a web part that would be added to the bottom of every library view and would display the folder content types making it easy to create a new folder (rather than having to go to documents - new document and then select from a drop-down).

My first attempt used

```
    foreach(SPContentType type in list.ContentTypes)
```

This works but it gives me the content types in some sort of default order that has nothing to do with the order I set in the New Document button.

My next attempt I used

```
    SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder(Request.RawUrl);
    foreach(SPContentType type in folder.ContentTypeOrder)
```

This also works but gives me the exact same order as the first attempt even though I have unique new button orders set for each folder type in the library.

So how do I get the order in which items appear on the new button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out I was getting the folder object incorrectly. There may be a more elegant way to do this, but the following works:

```
            SPFolder folder;
            string rawUrl = Request.RawUrl;
            string rootFolder;
            if (rawUrl.Contains("RootFolder"))
            {
                int start = rawUrl.IndexOf("RootFolder");
                int end = rawUrl.IndexOf("&", start);
                int length = end - start;
                rootFolder = rawUrl.Substring(start, length);
                string url = rootFolder.Replace("RootFolder=", "");
                folder = web.GetFolder(url);
            }
            else
            {
                folder = list.RootFolder;
            }


            foreach (SPContentType type in folder.ContentTypeOrder)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve list of content types that ordered the same way as items appear on the new button:

```
            SPFolder folder = list.RootFolder; 
            if (folder.ParentListId != Guid.Empty)
            {
                var contentTypeOrder = folder.ContentTypeOrder;
                foreach (var contentType in contentTypeOrder)
                {
                    //...
                }
            }
```

---

[SPFolder.ContentTypeOrder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.contenttypeorder%28v=office.12%29.aspx) property.

According to MSDN:

> This property returns a list of [SPContentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontenttype%28v=office.12%29.aspx) objects. The sequence of objects in the list determines the order in which content types are listed in the user interface, such as on a Sharepoint list’s New menu or on the List Settings page.